# Keeping two branches of an app project in sync: built framework and development repo

Tags: git

I have two branches of an app project which I would like to keep in sync with Git. One contains a Framework sub-project, which allows me to develop a framework alongside an app it is used in. The other is a version of the repo which contains the built framework, which is used by a third-party developer.

I'm having issues keeping them in sync. Essentially I want Git to ignore the "remove subproject" / "add framework" commits which are in the separate branches, but I keep having to redo things when I merge.

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining two branches in some kind of unnatural sync is never easy, I would suggest you to find a better solution and not work around it.

Possible solutions:

1. **Seperating repositories** and publishing the framework's subproject externally to the framework project as a module.
2. **Union the branches**, work with one "true" branch containing both framework, subproject and app in different 3 modules and create feature branches for your work with the agreement that person A modifies only the framework and person B modifies only the subproject and app.
   Even if you think you have some trust or preffesion issues, it is easier and safer than make the modification by yourself in every push.
   Also working with different users and tracking the branch tree will provide visibility and full control on the situation.
   Unless you work with big group of people you don't know, this is a feasible solution.

Comment: I already have something like suggestion 1. The app and framework are in separate repos. I wonder if its possible to ask Git to ignore specific commits, like inverse cherry-pick.

Comment: I don't fully understand how do you manage the repositories with merges if they seperate, do you mean you manually copy all the contents of one repository to the other every time you want to sync?  Anyway, "Inverse cherry-pick" is `git revert`. https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-revert